# c# Generics "in" keyword

Tags: c#, generics, contravariance

I've recently been assigned to some maintenance work on an existing application. I've come across the following code:

```
public interface IEntityService<T, in TKey>
{
    T GetEntityById(TKey id);    
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();    
    void Update(T entity);    
    void Delete(TKey key);
}
```

I'm not sure what the `in` keyword does for the second generic argument, `TKey`.

I came across the following MSDN Article which (should) explain it to me perfectly:
[in (Generic Modifier) (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx)

However, I don't *truly* understand it. Here's what it says:

> For generic type parameters, the in keyword specifies that the type
>   parameter is contravariant. You can use the in keyword in generic
>   interfaces and delegates.
>
> Contravariance enables you to use a less
>   derived type than that specified by the generic parameter. This allows
>   for implicit conversion of classes that implement variant interfaces
>   and implicit conversion of delegate types. Covariance and
>   contravariance in generic type parameters are supported for reference
>   types, but they are not supported for value types.
>
> A type can be
>   declared contravariant in a generic interface or delegate if it is
>   used only as a type of method arguments and not used as a method
>   return type. Ref and out parameters cannot be variant.
>
> An interface
>   that has a contravariant type parameter allows its methods to accept
>   arguments of less derived types than those specified by the interface
>   type parameter. For example, because in .NET Framework 4, in the
>   IComparer interface, type T is contravariant, you can assign an
>   object of the IComparer(Of Person) type to an object of the
>   IComparer(Of Employee) type without using any special conversion
>   methods if Employee inherits Person.
>
> A contravariant delegate can be
>   assigned another delegate of the same type, but with a less derived
>   generic type parameter.

I suppose this makes sense, but particularly citing

> Contravariance enables you to use a less derived type than that
>   specified by the generic parameter.

How can it be of any use to an `int`? Is there any "less derived type" I would ever pass in?

Comment: read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `int` is a value type, and as you quoted, *covariance and contravariance in generic type parameters are supported for reference types,* ***but they are not supported for value types***.

Comment: Thanks for that. So the answer is that it does nothing and probably shouldn't be there, right? Though it did teach me about variance and invariance! So no bad thing ;-)

Comment: @bgs264 I note that the only reference of `int` is in the last line of your question. Are you sure that `IEntityService` is to be used only with `int` keys? Probably it was built for [Compound Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) (primary keys composed of multiple columns)

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's the reason why it's like it is. Thanks, @xanatos. If you want to write it up into an answer somehow I'll accept it. Cheers.

Comment: I was just looking at one particular controller which had a few of these `IEntityService`s injected in, they all used `int` as their second type parameter, but yes, you're quite correct. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I note that the only reference of int is in the last line of your question. Are you sure that `IEntityService<>` is to be used only with `int` keys? Probably it was built for [Compound Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) (primary keys composed of multiple columns)

Now, in NHibernate for example, for compound keys you use a whole class to represent them, so you could have for a table `MyTable` a

```
class MyTableKey 
{ 
    public int Code;
    public int SubCode;
}
```

If you have a secondary table `MuSubtable` connected to that table you could then have

```
class MySubtableKey : MyTableKey 
{
    public int SubSubCode; 
}
```

where `MySubtable` is a table that has as the primary key the full primary key of `MyTable` (`Code` + `SubCode`) plus another field (`SubSubCode`).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two different entities, one has primary key column with data type as "integer" and another one is using a "string" type.

Then you could use IEntityService as:

```
public class PersonService : IEntityService<Person, int>
{
   int _id;
   ...
}

public class LogService : IEntityService<Log, string>
{
   string _id;        
   ...
}
```